# Iterate through Rails Activerecord model then execute script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to decrypt encrypted strings from column in db.

```
a=Model.select("column_name")

a.each do |i| 
   Encryptor.decrypt(Base64.decode64(i), :key=>'5b4b45ch5bch5cbh')
end
```

error I am getting is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `unpack' for #<Model:0x000000057a8438>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be:

```
a.each do |i|
  value = Encryptor.decrypt(Base64.decode64(i.column_name), :key=>'5b4b45ch5bch5cbh')
  i.update_attribute(column_name, value)
end
```

The problem is you pass `ActiveRecord` object into `Base64.decode64` method, while you should only pass string being specific DB column value.

Comment: I am getting back encrypted values in AR object. I should be getting decrypted values.

Comment: @user3566065 you say you want to modify those column values with value of your operation (`Encryptor.decrypt` etc.)?

Comment: wow yes that would be great! to modify those column values with value of your operation

Comment: Problem is am still getting encrypted values. I should be getting Decrypted values. It seems my script isnt executing for each iteration?

Comment: @user3566065 your script executes. Try this: `a.map { |i| Encryptor.decrypt(Base64.decode64(i.column_name), :key=>'5b4b45ch5bch5cbh') }` and check the returned array.

Comment: @user3566065 `map` returns array created of values returned from block evaluated for each element in your collection. `each` returns an object on which it was called, if I remember correctly.

Comment: could you have a look at my question how to update values: https://gist.github.com/ggeorgiev1/a211715c4dac5d2e2dae